# Canvas word wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have two text areas which go on the top and bottom of the canvas.

When you type, I need it the text to reach the edge of the canvas then break into a new line.

However, when you type a new word, it breaks into a new line. And if the word is long, it condenses the look of the word (opposite of stretching it wide.)

Here is my code:

```js
let topTextInput, bottomTextInput, topTextSizeInput, bottomTextSizeInput, imageInput, generateBtn, canvas, ctx;

function generateMeme (img, topText, bottomText, topTextSize, bottomTextSize) {
    let fontSize;

    // Size canvas to image
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 800;

    // Clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 
    // Draw main image
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Text style: white with black borders
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
 ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

    // Top text font size
    fontSize = canvas.width * topTextSize;
    ctx.font = fontSize + 'px Impact';
    ctx.lineWidth = fontSize / 20;

    // Draw top text
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
    topText.split(' ').forEach(function (t, i) {
        ctx.fillText(t, canvas.width / 2, i * fontSize, canvas.width);
        ctx.strokeText(t, canvas.width / 2, i * fontSize, canvas.width);
    });

    // Bottom text font size
    fontSize = canvas.width * bottomTextSize;
    ctx.font = fontSize + 'px Impact';
    ctx.lineWidth = fontSize / 20;

    // Draw bottom text
    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
    bottomText.split(' ').reverse().forEach(function (t, i) { // .reverse() because it's drawing the bottom text from the bottom up
        ctx.fillText(t, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - i * fontSize, canvas.width);
        ctx.strokeText(t, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - i * fontSize, canvas.width);
    });
}


function init () {
    // Initialize variables
    topTextInput = document.getElementById('top-text');
    bottomTextInput = document.getElementById('bottom-text');
    topTextSizeInput = 0.10;
    bottomTextSizeInput = 0.10;
    imageInput = document.getElementById('image-input');
    generateBtn = document.getElementById('generate-btn');
    canvas = document.getElementById('meme-canvas');
    
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = canvas.height = 0;

    // Default/Demo text
    topTextInput.value = bottomTextInput.value = 'Demo\nText';

    // Generate button click listener
    generateBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Read image as DataURL using the FileReader API
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            let img = new Image;
            img.src = reader.result;
            generateMeme(img, topTextInput.value, bottomTextInput.value, topTextSizeInput, bottomTextSizeInput);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(imageInput.files[0]);
    });
}

init();
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Meme Generator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="meme-generator.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <textarea id="top-text"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <textarea id="bottom-text"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="file" id="image-input" accept="image/*">
        </p>
        <p>
            <button id="generate-btn">Generate!</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <canvas id="meme-canvas" title="Right click -> &quot;Save image as...&quot;"></canvas>
        </p>
        <script src="meme-generator.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You stated your goal and pasted code, but you didn't ask a question.

Comment: please provide `html` code

Comment: Sorry. My question is how do I stop the shrinking of the words and make them go onto a new line. Also, how do I make the text reach the edge of the canvas before dropping down?